# Is it a common / accepted practice to assign multiple classes to a Bootstrapped div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, syntax, standards

I want to assign a Bootstrapped div `col-md-4` class and also assign a thumbnail class like so:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 thumbnail">
     <img src="http://goo.gl/0sX3jq">
</div>
```

Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are keeping bootstrap class intact, you can add n number of classes to div.
To be precise you can add thumbnail class to the div but make sure you are not overriding the properties mentioned in col-md-4 class.

Comment: I see, so if there is a padding assigned to the first class the second would override it, correct?
And thank you pranay!

Comment: It does not depend on which class you assign first and which one second. The rule of thumb is the latest property value encountered by rendering engine will be used. To override the property value you may use !important; along with css property value. Also you may go with CSS specificity rules for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one div can have multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks mate! Now just wondering if this alters behavior of the element at all in browsers. I'm currently editing in codecademy and the simulator is changing the positioning slightly when I assign two classes to the div.

Comment: Just make sure all the styles inside both classes are acceptable at all browser, and doesn't override each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LESS you can do something like this, this way you will short classes on element

**LESS**

```
.my-image{
    .thumbnail;
    .make-md-column(4);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-image">
     <img src="http://goo.gl/0sX3jq">
</div>
```

Or if you have something like this

```
<ol>

<li class="list-group-item">1</li>
<li class="list-group-item">2</li>
<li class="list-group-item">3</li>
<li class="list-group-item">4</li>
<li class="list-group-item">5</li>

</ol>
```

Easy do something like this

```
ol li{
.list-group-item;
}
```